# How to pass a variable from one file to another in php

Tags: php, html, sql

I am calling a value from my SQL database like so

```
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
```

I am then trying to read that value in another file

```
$order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['name'] . "</td>";
```

I have had some issues with other portions of passing data across as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80CcT.png). It helped me with one portion of my app but I have been unable to replicate it to the other variables. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been stuck on this for so long now I don't know what ways up..

UPDATE:
Order form

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Duvets & Pillows - Contact Us</title>
<meta name="Description" content="To purchase high quality curtain fabric, duvets, cushions, blinds and pillows. Also fabric for upholstery.">
<meta name="Keywords" content="Curtains, duvets, cushions, blinds, pillows, upholstery, fabric">
<meta name="verify-v1" content="kJvtha3o1pD/wr0uhRW2cxZqbf5YFn4psvLGt6xwqtg=" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body class="mainBody">
<table align="center" border="0" width="780" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td height="63"><img src="images/Interface/topbanner.jpg" alt="" width="780" height="63"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td height="63" bgcolor="#233368"><a href="http://www.homefabrics.co.nz"><img src="images/Interface/logo-panel.gif" border="0"></a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><table border="0" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="158" valign="top" bgcolor="#233368" style="width: 158px; border-width: 1px 0px 0px 0px; border-color: #fff; border-style: solid;"><span class="mainmenu"><a href="Page-page=1.php.html">Home</a></span><br><span class="mainmenu"><a href="Page-page=2.php.html">About Us</a></span><br><span class="mainmenu"><a href="Page-page=3.php.html">About Feather & Down</a></span><br><span class="mainmenu"><a href="Page-page=5.php.html">Duvets</a></span><br><span class="mainmenu"><a href="Page-page=8.php.html">Goose Down Pillows</a></span><br><span class="mainmenu"><a href="Page-page=9.php.html">Feather Beds</a></span><br><span class="mainmenuon">Contact Us</span></td>
        <td width="100%" valign="top" class="borderrightbottom" style="padding: 30px 40px 30px 40px;">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        <p><b>HOME FABRICS LIMITED</b></p>
        <p><b>Free delivery nationwide.</b></p>
        <p>Telephone: &nbsp;09 486 1103<br />
        Facsimile: 09 489 6136.<br />
        Email: <a href="mailto:sales@homefabrics.co.nz">sales@homefabrics.co.nz</a></p><p>Website:&nbsp;<a href="http://www.homefabrics.co.nz/">www.homefabrics.co.nz</a></p><p>28 Hurstmere Road<br />PO Box 33-024<br />Takapuna Beach<br />Auckland</p><h2>ORDER FORM</h2><br /> 

        <p><i>Required fields are marked with</i> <b>*</b></p>

<form action="orderformDNP.php" method="post"
onsubmit="document.getElementById('myButton').disabled=true;
document.getElementById('myButton').value='Submitting...';"
>

<table width="496" border="0" style="border-width: 1px; border-color:#E5E5E5;
border-style: solid;">
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">
            Name: *
        </td>
        <td width="60%">
            <input type="text" name="yourname" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">
            Phone Number: *
        </td>
        <td width="60%">
            <input type="text" name="phonenumber" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">
            Mobile Number: 
        </td>
        <td width="60%">
            <input type="text" name="mobilenumber" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">
            E-mail: *
        </td>
        <td width="60%">
            <input type="text" name="email" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">
            Deliver Address: *
        </td>
        <td width="60%">
            <textarea name="deliveryaddress" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 </br>


<!-- this is the ordering part of the form --!>

 <h3>Duvets</h3>

<?php

//Start session
    //session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }



$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 5050goosedown ORDER BY price ASC");

echo "<table border='0' width='496'>
<tr>
<th width='30%'><b>50/50 Goose Down:</b></th>
<th width='30%'><i>Normal Fill / Our Fill</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Old Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
</tr>";

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
  if($i%2 == 0){
      echo "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
  }
  $i++;

  if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0)){
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "   -" . $row['width'] . "/" . $row['height'] .  "</td>";
  }
  echo "<td>" . $row['normal_fill'] . "/" . $row['our_fill'] . "</td>";
  if ($row['old_price'] !=0){
    echo "<td>" . $row['old_price'] . "</td>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<td></td>";
  }
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";

  echo '<td><select name="5050goosedown[' . $row['goosedown_id'] . ']">'
                ."<option value=''> 0 </option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>
        </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

?>
</br></br>
<?php

//Start session
    //session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 5050duckdown ORDER BY price ASC");

echo "<table border='0' width='496'>
<tr>
<th width='30%'><b>50/50 Duck Down:</b></th>
<th width='30%'><i>Normal Fill / Our Fill</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
</tr>";

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
  if($i%2 == 0){
      echo "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
  }
  $i++;

  if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0)){
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "   -" . $row['width'] . "/" . $row['height'] .  "</td>";
  }
  echo "<td>" . $row['normal_fill'] . "/" . $row['our_fill'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td><select name="5050duckdown[' . $row['duckdown_id'] . ']">'
                ."<option value=''> 0 </option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>
        </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

?>
</br></br>
<?php

//Start session
    //session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 955goosedown ORDER BY price ASC");

echo "<table border='0' width='496'>
<tr>
<th width='30%'><b>95/5 Goose Down:</b></th>
<th width='30%'><i>Normal Fill / Our Fill</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Old Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
</tr>";

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
  if($i%2 == 0){
      echo "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
  }
  $i++;

  if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0)){
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "   -" . $row['width'] . "/" . $row['height'] .  "</td>";
  }
  echo "<td>" . $row['normal_fill'] . "/" . $row['our_fill'] . "</td>";
  if ($row['old_price'] !=0){
    echo "<td>" . $row['old_price'] . "</td>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<td></td>";
  }
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td><select name="955goosedown[' . $row['955goosedown_id'] . ']">'
                ."<option value=''> 0 </option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>
        </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

?>
</br>
<h3>Pillows</h3>

<?php

//Start session
    //session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM goosedownpillows ORDER BY price ASC");

echo "<table border='0' width='496'>
<tr>
<th width='62.5%'><b>Goose Down Pillows:</b></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
</tr>";

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
  if($i%2 == 0){
      echo "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
  }
  $i++;

  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td><select name="goosedownpillows[' . $row['goosedownpillows_id'] . ']">'
                ."<option value=''> 0 </option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>
        </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

?>
</br>
<h3>Feather Mattress Toppers</h3>

<?php

//Start session
    //session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM feathermattresstoppers ORDER BY price ASC");

echo "<table border='0' width='496'>
<tr>
<th width='62.5%'><b>95/5 Mattress Toppers:</b></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Old Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
</tr>";

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
  if($i%2 == 0){
      echo "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
  }
  $i++;

  if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0)){
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "   -" . $row['width'] . "/" . $row['height'] .  "</td>";
  }
  if ($row['old_price'] !=0){
    echo "<td>" . $row['old_price'] . "</td>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<td></td>";
  }
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td><select name="feathermattresstoppers[' . $row['feathermattresstoppers_id'] . ']">'
                ."<option value=''> 0 </option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>
        </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

?>





<p><b>Additional Info:</b><br />
<textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>
</br></br>

Access code: <input type="text" name="code" /><br />
Please enter <i>MYCODE</i> above. </br></br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="myButton" />

        </td>

    </tr>
</table>

</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Email form** (this is upposed to recive the values from order form)

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $body_items = '';
    $total_price = 0;


    /* Set Redgraves Email address, so they receive the orders  */
    $myemail  = "kcwebz@gmail.com";

    /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
    $yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'], "Enter your name");
    $phonenumber = check_input($_POST['phonenumber'], "Enter your phone number");
    $mobilenumber = check_input($_POST['mobilenumber']);
    $email    = check_input($_POST['email'], "Enter your E-mail address");
    $deliveryaddress = check_input($_POST['deliveryaddress'], "Enter your delivery address");

    $comments = check_input($_POST['comments']);

    $random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10);

    $goosedown_id = ($_POST[$row['goosedown_id']]); 




    if (strtolower($_POST['code']) != 'mycode') 
    {
        die('Wrong access code');
    }

    /* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
    {
        show_error("E-mail address not valid");
    }

    /* If phone number has characters show error message */
    if (preg_match("/\D/",$phonenumber))
    {
        die("Please enter numbers only for Phone Number");
    }

    /* If mobile number has characters show error message */
    if (preg_match("/\D/",$mobilenumber))
    {
        die("Please enter numbers only for Mobile Number");
    }


    // 5050duckdown
    $flag = 0;
    $i = 1;
    $order_content = '';
    foreach ($_POST['5050goosedown'] as $key => $value ) {
        if ($value > 0) {
            $flag = 1;
            if($i%2 == 0)
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
            else
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
            $i++;

            if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0))
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['5050goosedown'][$key]['name'] . "</td>";
            else
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['5050goosedown'][$key]['name'] . "   -" . $_SESSION['5050goosedown'][$key]['width'] . "/" . $_SESSION['5050goosedown'][$key]['height'] .  "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $_SESSION['5050goosedown'][$key]['price'] . "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $value . "</td>";

            $sub = $_SESSION['5050goosedown'][$key]['price'] * $value;
            $total_price += $sub;
            $order_content .= "<td>" . $sub . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }

    if ($flag == 1) {
        $body_items .= "<table border='0' width='600'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='30%'><b>50/50 Goose Down:</b></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Item Price</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
                            </tr>";
        $body_items .= $order_content;
        $body_items .= '</table><br /><br />';
    }

    //////////////
    $flag = 0;
    $i = 1;
    $order_content = '';
    foreach ($_POST['5050duckdown'] as $key => $value ) {
        if ($value > 0) {
            $flag = 1;
            if($i%2 == 0)
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
            else
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
            $i++;

            if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0))
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['name'] . "</td>";
            else
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['name'] . "   -" . $_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['width'] . "/" . $_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['height'] .  "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['price'] . "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $value . "</td>";

            $sub = $_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['price'] * $value;
            $total_price += $sub;
            $order_content .= "<td>" . $sub . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }

    if ($flag == 1) {
        $body_items .= "<table border='0' width='600'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='30%'><b>50/50 Duck Down:</b></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Item Price</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
                            </tr>";
        $body_items .= $order_content;
        $body_items .= '</table><br /><br />';
    }

    /////////////////
    $flag = 0;
    $i = 1;
    $order_content = '';
    foreach ($_POST['955goosedown'] as $key => $value ) {
        if ($value > 0) {
            $flag = 1;
            if($i%2 == 0)
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
            else
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
            $i++;

            if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0))
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['955goosedown'][$key]['name'] . "</td>";
            else
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['955goosedown'][$key]['name'] . "   -" . $_SESSION['955goosedown'][$key]['width'] . "/" . $_SESSION['955goosedown'][$key]['height'] .  "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $_SESSION['955goosedown'][$key]['price'] . "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $value . "</td>";

            $sub = $_SESSION['955goosedown'][$key]['price'] * $value;
            $total_price += $sub;
            $order_content .= "<td>" . $sub . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }

    if ($flag == 1) {
        $body_items .= "<table border='0' width='600'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='30%'><b>95/5 Goose Down:</b></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Item Price</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
                            </tr>";
        $body_items .= $order_content;
        $body_items .= '</table><br /><br />';
    }

    //////
    $flag = 0;
    $i = 1;
    $order_content = '';
    foreach ($_POST['goosedownpillows'] as $key => $value ) {
        if ($value > 0) {
            $flag = 1;
            if($i%2 == 0)
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
            else
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
            $i++;

            if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0))
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['goosedownpillows'][$key]['name'] . "</td>";
            else
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['goosedownpillows'][$key]['name'] . "   -" . $_SESSION['goosedownpillows'][$key]['width'] . "/" . $_SESSION['goosedownpillows'][$key]['height'] .  "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $_SESSION['goosedownpillows'][$key]['price'] . "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $value . "</td>";

            $sub = $_SESSION['goosedownpillows'][$key]['price'] * $value;
            $total_price += $sub;
            $order_content .= "<td>" . $sub . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }

    if ($flag == 1) {
        $body_items .= "<table border='0' width='600'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='30%'><b>Goose Down Pillows:</b></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Item Price</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
                            </tr>";
        $body_items .= $order_content;
        $body_items .= '</table><br /><br />';
    }

    //////
    $flag = 0;
    $i = 1;
    $order_content = '';
    foreach ($_POST['feathermattresstoppers'] as $key => $value ) {
        if ($value > 0) {
            $flag = 1;
            if($i%2 == 0)
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
            else
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
            $i++;

            if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0))
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['feathermattresstoppers'][$key]['name'] . "</td>";
            else
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['feathermattresstoppers'][$key]['name'] . "   -" . $_SESSION['feathermattresstoppers'][$key]['width'] . "/" . $_SESSION['feathermattresstoppers'][$key]['height'] .  "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $_SESSION['feathermattresstoppers'][$key]['price'] . "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $value . "</td>";

            $sub = $_SESSION['feathermattresstoppers'][$key]['price'] * $value;
            $total_price += $sub;
            $order_content .= "<td>" . $sub . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }

    if ($flag == 1) {
        $body_items .= "<table border='0' width='600'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='30%'><b>95/5 Mattress Toppers:</b></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Item Price</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
                            </tr>";
        $body_items .= $order_content;
        $body_items .= '</table><br /><br />';
    }
    $body_items .= "<br /><b>Total: $total_price</b></b></b>";



/*-------------------First Email--------------------*/

    /* Set Email for Redgraves, so they can for-full the order form */
    $message = "A order form has been submitted by: $yourname<br /><br />

    Order number :<u>$random</u><br /><br />

    <b>Name:</b> $yourname<br />
    <b>E-mail:</b> $email<br />
    <b>Phone Number:</b> $phonenumber<br />
    <b>Mobile Number:</b> $mobilenumber<br />
    <b>Delivery Address:</b> $deliveryaddress<br />
    <b>Comments:</b> $comments<br /><br />

    $body_items


    <br /><br />**End of message**
    ";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
    $header= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header.= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    mail($myemail, "Order Submitted", $message, $header);

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    //mail($myemail, "Order Submitted", $message);

/*---------------Second Email---------------------*/    

    /* This email is to confirm the order and act as a receipt to the purchaser */
    $respond_message = "Order Completed<br /><br />

    Your order has been submitted! details are as follows<br /><br />

    <b>Name:</b> $yourname<br />
    <b>E-mail:</b> $email<br />
    <b>Phone Number:</b> $phonenumber<br />
    <b>Mobile Number:</b> $mobilenumber<br />
    <b>Delivery Address:</b> $deliveryaddress<br />
    <b>Comments:</b> $comments<br /><br />

    $body_items


    <br /><b>Reference Number:</b> <u>$random</u><br /><br />

    Please make payment using the refrence number above within 7 working days or your order will be canceled <br />
    ASB 000-0000-0000-00 ";

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    mail($email, "Thank you for your order", $respond_message, $headers);


    /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
    header('Location: thankyou.html');
exit();




/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}




function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

the order form should produce a table like this.. as you can see the value are missing from it.

[image]

Comment: u want to pass value on submit form???

Comment: To make any content accessible to another 'file', you should either create a POST (so use a form) or a GET (append your variables to the query string). Or pass it through a SESSION, like you seem to do. I need some more code context in order to come with a correct solution.

Comment: dev yes, yossarian I have all the code showing in my first question which shows my post method etc. I can copy it across to here but wasnt sure if thats what I am supposed to do or not.

Comment: I have just realise $_SESSION is calling from my DB.. tring to figure out now why its going wrong. or if thats even the case.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>\n";
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
```

---

```
$order_content .= "<td>" . $_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['name'] . "</td>\n";
```

But please review the code `$_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['name']` if it's right. If not, then just chance it to `$_SESSION['5050duckdown'] . $_SESSION[$key] . $_SESSION['name']`

But please, don't forget the `session_start();` function before the opening `<html>` tag, and the first file where we tried to assign the row into a session must be run first before running the second file where the session assigning to a variable.

Comment: Try to see the output of `$_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]` on your project thought `echo` and report back the result!

Answer (score 0):

> You have 2 option:
>
> Either u create cookie or session and you can also tr  global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code like.

```
<?php    
session_start();

  //print_r($_SESSION);
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>\n";
  $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];

?>
```

and use it in other file like.

```
$order_content .= "<td>" . $_SESSION['name'] . "</td>\n";
```

May be its works.

Comment: I had session_start(); but I added print_r($_SESSION); and I got this in my confirmation screen **Array ( [ERRMSG_ARR] => Array ( [0] => Login ID missing [1] => Password missing ) [SESS_MEMBER_ID] => 1 [SESS_FIRST_NAME] => John [SESS_LAST_NAME] => Smith )**

Comment: this means your value is not set in session?

Comment: where you set your value to session. please add complete code?

Comment: I have added the code of my order form and email form, with the idea of the order form passing the values to the email form... any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just tried your code example.. again unfortunatly it didnt work. I am going to have to pay someone to fix this cause I am out of ideas. thanks for our help

Answer (score 0):

you can also use ? operator

```
   Ex. 
   // order_form.php

   $id = 7;          //and you want sent on order_edit.php
   order_edit.php?id=$id;      // set variable in anchor tag or where you want


  // order_edit.php 

  $id = $_GET['id'];       // get value of id from url
```